# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tweet'

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

My console is saying: "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tweet' "

I'm using jQuery 1.9.1, and Twitter Bootstrap 2.3

My staging environment is at: http://rsatestamls.kaliocommerce.com/

My entire JS file is at: http://rsatestamls.kaliocommerce.com/Javascript/custom.js

My JS code for the twitter area is:

```
// Twitter
     $("#twitter").tweet({
      join_text: "auto",
      username: "amleonardinc", //replace this with your username
     // modpath: './twitter/',
      avatar_size: 32,
      count: 3,
      auto_join_text_default: "we said,",
      auto_join_text_ed: "we",
      auto_join_text_ing: "we were",
      auto_join_text_reply: "we replied",
      auto_join_text_url: "we were checking out",
      loading_text: "loading tweets..."
    });

 })
```

Comment: As the error clearly states, there is no such function.  Why do you expect that to exist?

Comment: Did you include the plugin js file for tweet()?

Comment: you do not have the plugin "tweet" in your project

Comment: Haha, you're all correct. Wow, I totally over looked that. I had the file on my desktop but not in the actual project. oi. More coffeee...

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Didn't have jQuery Twitter plugin. I derped and forgot it.